Feet on table connected to another table with Torah books
I understand that it is forbidden to put one's feet on a table that has Torah books.
What if the Torah books are on one table, which is connected to the table one wishes to put one's feet up on? Either directly attached, or just lined up and touching.

Why put your feet on a table at all?  As the Ramban taught repeatedly, holiness is moderating yourself even with what is permitted. :-)
